# JEST keeps trying to parse CSS module even after using identity-obj-proxy

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using css modules with sass in a React application.
I used identity-obj-proxy but it is not working for css modules, it works for normal scss files.
I have jest configuration setup in jest.config.js and I am sure that it is being read correctly.

**App.js**

```
import scss from '@project/styles/js-variables.scss';
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@app(.*)$': '<rootDir>/app$1',
    '^@project(.*)$': '<rootDir>/app/projects/NBK$1',
    '\\.(scss|sass|css)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/testing/mocks/fileMock.js',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(@amcharts)\\/).+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$'],
};
```

**js-variables.scss**

```
@import '~@project/styles/colors';
@import '~@project/styles/variables';

:export {
  mainColor: $main-color;
  bodyColor: $body-black;
  backgroundColor: $dropdown-background-color;
}
```

I have tried everything, using transform and custom mappers but nothing is working.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should move `'\\.(scss|sass|css)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'` to the top entry of your `moduleNameMapper` object. As the ordering matters, your `.scss` file import is being matched against `'^@project(.*)$'` first.

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(scss|sass|css)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/testing/mocks/fileMock.js',
    '^@app(.*)$': '<rootDir>/app$1',
    '^@project(.*)$': '<rootDir>/app/projects/NBK$1',
}
```